# Laravel5.3でプレインテキストのメールを送信すると改行が消えてしまう

Tags: php, laravel-5, mail

Laravelの5.3の[公式ドキュメントに記載されている方法](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)でメール送信処理を作成しているのですが、プレインテキストでメールを送信しようとすると、改行が全て消えてしまいます。

改行したい箇所に、 `{{ "\n" }}` と記載することで改行させることはできるのですが、改行後に空白スペースが入ってしまう問題がありますし、できれば改行用に文字を入れる方法は取りたくありません。（それが正しい方法でしたら教えていただきたいです・・・・。）

Mailableのクラスと送信処理を記載させていただきますので、問題がありそうな箇所をご指摘いただきたいです。

### app/Mail/OrderShipped.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
    * 注文インスタンス
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $params;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("test subject")->text('mails.test');
    }
}
```

### 送信処理

```
$orderShipped = new OrderShipped(['price' => 9999]);
Mail::to('test@example.com')->send($orderShipped);
```

### Viewファイル

resources/views/mails/test.blade.php

```
テストメール

テストテストテストテスト
テストテストテストテスト
```

Comment: Viewテンプレートの改行コードはどうなってますか？といってもLFでもCRLFでも改行が消えることは無いはずですが……。

Comment: @hinaloe コメントありがとうございます！！！自己解決しました。。。。HtmlMinというライブラリを有効にしていたために、改行コードが消されていました・・・！

Comment: 自己解決した場合は回答としてそれを投稿しておいてくださいね：）(セルフ回答の承認は日を置く必要がありますが。)

Comment: なるほど！了解です！投稿します！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました！HtmlMinというライブラリを有効にしていたために、改行コー‌​ドが消されていました！

Answer (score 1):

test.blade.phpの改行させたい箇所にbrタグを入れてみてください。
それで改行できますよ٩( ᐛ )و

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！！当然のことながらHTMLとして表示した場合は、改行して表示されましたが、やはりテキスト形式で表示させた場合は、改行されませんでした・・・。